# find multiple patterns in large data

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching, recommendation-engine, pattern-recognition

My problem is:
I have a table having guidlist and workflow name( Suppose any relevant name).
Input will be 5 guids as a string.

Operation: 
I want to check presence of input in each row of above table in column guidlist.
I also want to find the relevancy of search result found.

Like
suppose input guids are G1,G2,G3,G4,G5
Note: "--" represents more guids present

1. so most relevant search pattern will be if found in Guidlist like
   ----G1,G2,G3,G4,G5-----
2. second most relevant pattern will be ---G1G2G3G4---- or ----G2G3G4G5----
3. third most relevant pattern will be ---G1G2G3---- and ----G2G3G4--- and ---G3G4G5---
4. fourth relevant will be --G1--G2--G3--G4--G5-- if guids between input guids
   is maximum 2. i.e. Maximum 2 guids can be there between G1 and G2 or
   G2 and G3 etc.
5. fifth relevant pattern will be -----G1--G2--G3--G4---- or ----G2--G3--G4--G5-- if guids between input guids is maximum 2. i.e. Maximum 2 guids can be there between G1 and G2 or G2 and G3 etc.
6. sixth relevant pattern will be -----G1--G2--G3---- or ----G2--G3--G4-- or --G3--G4--G5-- if guids between input guids is maximum 2. i.e. Maximum 2 guids can be there between G1 and G2 or G2 and G3 etc.
7. If any above is not found then we will match that after shuffling input if it is present like --G2--G1--G3--G4--G5-- or any other order.

Please tell me is there any existing algorithm to achieve this pattern recognition.

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Is there any specific part you are not getting. I will improve that